# how to download an xml file from a remote server to my server at the same time each night

Tags: asp.net, xml, curl

Hi been looking at this with no idea where to go next - do I use curl / .dat file... Has anyone done this before.

The problem is getting a fresh XML file from a remote server each night ( as I have to go to a URL with login details - API - that displays my XML feed.. ) 
[it expires after set time limit of a few hours ] and need to save it into onto my server...  (using a 1and1 Windows shared server).

Any help would be great, thanks Simon

Comment: I'm confused, do you have to login via some kind of form or is there a login via the api? What have you tried?

Comment: I go to a URL get with ID and Password this then generates a XML file which I need to back up every night....  What have I tired, nothing as yet as not sure which why to go - cURL or Dat File...

Comment: Say at midnight, how do I automatic make a call to a remote server to get (using a fixed URL) this returns a XML file that I need next to save this to my shared server...  Hope that explains it a bit better...